# Ionic build in Docker container with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, ionic-framework

I was playing around with Ionic the last couple of days and now i want to deploy my website in a Docker Container with nginx on it.

But there is a problem with the Routing: If i type in the IP-Adress of my server with the port (e.g.: `http://10.0.0.1/`) I will directly redirected to the Dashboard (`http://10.0.0.1/dashboard`).

As far so good: But if I press F5 in the Dashboard tab I get an 404 Not Found error.

I already read lots of Stackoverflow articles about this, the most of them say to change the nginx config. So here is my config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index       index.html;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: when you say you get a 404 ...is it the network tab that says 404 from api or is it an ionic routing error? If it is an ionic routing error please post your router code.

Comment: I think it is the api?
The full message I get on F5 is:

`404 Not Found
nginx/1.21.6`

How do i check if its an rounting error?